# Flag individual comments or flag once for many?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags

When multiple comments on a single post need attention, what works best for the diamond moderator workflow?

- Flag each comment
- Flag one comment and use the "Other" section to indicate which comments should be addressed
- Something else

For example, in exchanges such as:

> Person A: Post your code
>
> Person B: You should really post your code
>
> OP: Okay, I posted the code

The first two are obsolete after the edit, and the third will be obsolete after the first two are removed.

I assume that there may be specific cases where one is better than the other, such as those that trigger an automatic reaction.

Which method should be used to reduce the overall workload?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Example custom moderator flag on the post itself:

> This comment thread has degenerated into a mud-slinging contest.  Please prune or purge.

No need to fuss over mechanics.  Just tell us what's wrong and what you think we need to do to fix it.

Comment: Comment flags have gained a lot more visibility since 2013. Does this still work as well today?